# Where can I locate cache of recent login pictures for OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, login, osx-mountain-lion

I have a whole bunch of image icons stuck inside of my recent pictures tab in my login pictures box for Mountain Lion. I was looking to clean it out, but I can't seem to delete them through the methods I have used. I tried using a keyboard shortcut, dragging the recents to the trash, and tried to find them through the Finder. Does anyone happen to know where Mountain Lion stores these files? I know they used to be in the iChat folder until they got rid of iChat for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X **10.6.x** you can find them under:

```
~/Library/Images/iChat Recent Pictures
```

as *tiff* files…

I guess you have to edit the *Recents.plist* other than delete the pictures…